# Space between toolbar (in Activity) and tablayout (in fragment)

Tags: android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-appbarlayout

I am developing an app in which I have to implement tablayout in a fragment, while the toolbar itself remains on the main frame of the activity. note that, I need multiple transactions of fragment and only one has tablayout. The code works completely fine. But the problem is there is a gap between the toolbar and tablayout on the first run. If I chage the fragment and get back to it, the gap is gone. How can I fix this??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXDXk.jpg)

In the Activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="thanatos.perkyrabbit.edumanager.Activities.GuardianPrivilegesActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_guardian_privileges">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu_guardian_privileges"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

in the fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="thanatos.perkyrabbit.edumanager.Fragments.Guardian.StudentProgressFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        app:tabTextColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/student_progress_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

In the StudentProgressFragment xml, change

android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

to

android:fitsSystemWindows="false"